# Clearing out a static variable in a method

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, static, dispatch

In one of my methods, I am using dispatch_once for which I have created a static variable. The method is working as expected and the unit tests are passing successfully when ran individually. But when I run the tests all at once, one of the test fails because of the value being hold by the static variable inside the method.

***My Method:***

```
+ (NSString *)myMethod
{
    static NSString *dayOfTheWeek;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
       // Do something.

        dayOfTheWeek = @"Monday";

        if (!dayOfTheWeek)
        {
            dayOfTheWeek = @"Sunday";
        }
    });

    return dayOfTheWeek;
}
```

***Question:***

So I have unit tests to test for "Monday" and another unit test to test "Sunday". If I execute both these tests separately on XCODE, they pass, but when I execute them together, the test for "Sunday" fails, since my static variable is still holding the value "Monday".

Is there a way I can clear out the method level static variable just for test purpose? Or is there any other way I can successfully execute both the tests?

Comment: "clear out the method level static variable" is not possible in standard mechanism, AFAIK.

Comment: This should probably not be a class method, and in any case it should not use a static. Keep in mind that a static knows nothing about instances - it operates at the level of the _file_ - so it will be the same for every instance of this class throughout the lifetime of the app.

Comment: OP, i wish you would just explain what you are trying to do. this does look "all wrong" at this point.

Comment: what about moving the static value outside or make it into a parameter

Answer (score 5):

Conditional logic almost never belongs in a `dispatch_once()` block. If there is some kind of logic that could be different on different executions, then it probably needs to be reevaluated more often than once per program execution. It's not clear what the logic is, but if it's something like "what is today?" then, what happens if your program runs for multiple days?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have incorrectly designed this method. Two considerations:

**(1)** Once means *once*. You cannot make a half-once contract. This code will be executed once *over the entire life of the app*. It doesn't matter how many times you call it, whether you change the inputs, whether you make a new instance of this class, etc.

**(2)** What you want to do is study the concept of *memoization*. This is when you match up the input with the output for a time-consuming calculation. A good model is a mutable dictionary. When an input arrives, you look in the dictionary *for that input*. If the result is there, return it; if it isn't there, perform your calculation, put the result there, and return it. In this way you avoid doing a time-consuming calculation *for each possible input*.

Answer (score 0):

I think `myMethod` need refactoring for testability. Like below:

```
// NOT THREAD-SAFE
static NSString *dayOfTheWeek;
+ (void) myMethodSetValue(NSString* value)
{
    dayOfTheWeek = value;
}

+ (NSString*) myMethodGetValue()
{
    return dayOfTheWeek;
}

+ (NSString *)myMethod
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        myMethodSetValue(&dayOfTheWeek, @"Monday");
    });

    return myMethodGetValue();
}
```

Test1

```
myMethodSetValue(@"Monday");
...
test routine
```

Test2

```
myMethodSetValue(@"Sunday");
...
test routine
```